# INSERT INTO an Integer after Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have a big problem and really need your help!

I have a trigger on a table `Table A` which updates few lines and at the end I am making an `INSERT INTO` another table `Table B` with data from the table `Table A` where have the trigger on it.

Everything is fine, only that I have an INT column `DOCID` in `Table B` which I can't fill with an `INT` Column from `Table A (VERID)`. If I insert a `NVARCHAR` variable into the column `DOCID`, it's working. I also can take a `NVARCHAR` field vom `Table A`  and insertit in the `INT` column `DOCID`. But no way for `INT` into `INT`. Here is the Code:

```
declare @stichwortid as varchar(50)
select  @stichwortid= isnull(VERID,'') from inserted

INSERT INTO [dbo].[BAUFIN_KOSTENSTELLEN] (DOCID, DWKEYWORD) VALUES(@stichwortid, 'test')
```

Also trying to declare `@stiwchwortid` as `INT` didn't work either. Filling it into the second column `DWKEYWORD` is also no problem.

Comment: What is t he problem you are encountering?

Comment: I can't see no INT variable or field. If DOCID is INT why have you define @stichwortid as varchar()?

Comment: I also tried to define @stichwortid as INT before, thought this way would help...

Comment: Now I have something new! I tried another Source columg which is also INt and it worked! There was only 1 number in it. The VERID has 6 or 7 numbers. Could it be the length? Now  I am really confused!

Answer (score 0):

How about using `insert . . . select`?

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[BAUFIN_KOSTENSTELLEN] (DOCID, DWKEYWORD)
    SELECT verid, 'test'
    FROM inserted;
```

Your code, as written, should work.  Despite your statement otherwise, the most likely culprit is that the data type is different in the two tables -- which can cause other sorts of problems.

Comment: Thank you. This didn't work. Also ericpap suggestion didn't work. If I insert  from the source a column which is a nvarchar, it works! No problem! I have only the problem that the source and the column I want to fill in are both int! That's the only reason I can see...

Comment: I also can fill the int source into a nvarchar field, but not into my int field.

Answer (score 0):

If DOCID is an INT Column, you can try:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[BAUFIN_KOSTENSTELLEN] (DOCID, DWKEYWORD)
SELECT CAST (verid as INT), 'test'
FROM inserted;
```

Comment: Thank you. This didn't work. Both, the source and the columng I want to fill in are INT. 
If I insert  from the source a column which is a nvarchar, it works! No problem! I have only the problem that the source and the column I want to fill in are both int! That's the only reason I can see...

Comment: I also can fill the int source into a nvarchar field, but not into my int field.

Comment: What type of field are verid and DocID? Could be that there is some restrictions on docID column values? What is the error you are getting?